# iOS keyboard set state

Tags: ios, keyboard, state

The problem I am faced with, is that the (default) keyboard on iOS is in its first state (default - qwerty) when starting to type in a textfield, and I would like this state to be the (default - number) state, which is seen when the user presses the ".?123" button. Is there any way to set this state initially?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - Iphone. How can I show the numeric keyboard by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796772/objective-c-iphone-how-can-i-show-the-numeric-keyboard-by-default)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this from your TextFieldDelegate

```
TextField.keyboardType =UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

If you are using IB, change Keyboard type to "Numbers And Punctuation" from attribute inspector

Comment: Read the question again. This is not what the OP is asking for

Comment: Note, that if you want ?123, and not only numbers, you can use `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation`

Comment: @EsbenB .. I would suggest you the same.. "Is there any way to set this state initially?" this line should be read carefully..

Comment: What he meant was the keyboard 'view' you get when you press the `.?123` key on the default keyboard. Not the num pad keyboard.

Comment: The OP is asking for a way to set the keyboard in the state achieved by pushing the "?123" button. Not the NumberPad keyboard

Comment: @n00bProgrammer.. Yeah.. sorry.. changed it.. :)

Comment: @Larme I will try your solution, and see if it gives the desired result.

Comment: @D3vinno.. Larme's answer is right. I was In hurry posting answer. Have updated my answer now..